# MYSQL update a table based on another table's data

Tags: mysql

I have 2 MySQL tables like these

1. Table main

| email | bounce | status |

2. Table bounce

|email |

what i want is a query to update the (bounce and status column) main table with respect to the data from bounce table

this is the query i tried, `update main inner join bounce on (main.email = bounce.email) set main.bounce='yes' and main.status='Inactive';`

Comment: Hey. I can't understand how bounce table can affect main table. I get that bounce has the email that main has, but according to which fields from bounce would you like to update main with?

Comment: email field is the only field similar on both tables.

Comment: So you want to update the bounce column to "yes" and status column to "Inactive" if a mail from main table exists in bounce table?

Comment: yes, exactly like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the column name in main table is same as the 2nd table name "bounce" , that's why update statement didn't work
`update main inner join bounce on (main.email = bounce.email) set main.bounce='yes' and main.status='Inactive';`
from the above query, `main.bounce` doesn't represents the column in main table instead it points to the second table "bounce"
You can update the table by either

1. change the name of the second table and run the update statement or
2. update the 2 columns separately 
   `update main inner join bounce on (main.email = bounce.email) set main.status='Inactive';`
   `update main set bounce='yes' where status='Inactive';`

Answer (score 1):

You should try

```sql
UPDATE main m
INNER JOIN bounce b
ON m.email=b.email
SET m.bounce="yes" AND m.status="Inactive";
```

Comment: rows are matched from 2 tables but its not updating [used mysql workbench]
`0 row(s) affected Rows matched: 5719  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0`

Comment: The above query should work. Are you sure that there are records that can be updated?

Comment: its showing 5719 records matched right, and i cross checked the numbers also. Rows are matching but not updating, this is the same response i got for my query also `update main inner join bounce on (main.email = bounce.email) set main.bounce='yes' and main.status='Inactive';`

Comment: Yeah it matched but it might already be updated. When you select * from main can you see the results that you were expecting?

Comment: yeah, i checked the main table
`select count(*) from main where bounce='yes';`
still not updated